# How to optimize simple stack-machine code?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, stack-machine

I've been playing around with a simple stack-based language, and one of the things that I've found myself doing repeatedly is manually optimizing chunks of code.

I figured "hey, this looks very much like something that a computer can do! Repetitive work with a clear goal and semantics.". But looking around, I can't find much of anything on optimizing stack machine code. Register machines, yes. But not stack-based languages. It seems like the general response to "how do you optimize stack machine code?" is "don't."

So: how does one go about optimizing stack machine code? Are there any general methods beyond simple peephole optimizations? Are there any methods of generating peephole optimizations automatically?

Comment: to make your question answerable, not too broad and on-topic - please add code sample of RoboWar code before optimization and same code after your manual optimization (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For instance whole [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvm) is also stack based. Used on desktops, servers, Android etc.

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit, I realized something. RoboWar is just a context - I am interested in stack machine optimization techniques in general, not specifically for RoboWar. I have removed the discussion of RoboWar entirely, lest people get the wrong idea.

Comment: although I tried to give you some answer, I'm voting -1 as this question is too broad, does not show any code, very little research effort was shown and does not fit the site [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) format. If you want code-less question you should move it to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or even better to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1** [Wikipedia - Stack Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) lists some stack machines and stack-based languages (*that might somehow address the optimization*)

**1.1** my reading of the various links led me to the conclusion that stack-based machines are just a theoretical tool. No need to "optimize" them as in order to run a program such machines translate the stack-based code into a register-based code, optimize it and run it on register-based hardware. This process is usually called [Just In Time compilation (JIT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) or [Ahead Of Time compilation (AOT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation)

**2** out of the listed options [Wikipedia - FORTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) describes >40 years old wide-spread stack-based programming language (*there should be some optimization-related materials available*)

**3** Google search for "forth stack machine optimization" gives some lots of articles, e.g.

- The J1 Forth CPU, http://www.excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html
- A Preliminary Exploration of Optimized Stack Code Generation, http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack_compiler/stack_co.html
- Stack Optimisation - Dr. Peter J. Knaggs, http://www.rigwit.co.uk/thesis/chap-5.pdf
- Design and Implementation of an Efficient Stack Machine, http://www.jopdesign.com/doc/stack.pdf
- ...

Comment: "my reading of the various links led me to the conclusion that stack-based machines are just a theoretical tool." So is Brainfuck, and yet there are still optimizers for it.

Comment: The links were helpful, however.

Comment: You call stack machines a theoretical tool, and then you referenced the J1 CPU which is an actual hardware stack machine, which doesn't translate the stack-based code into register-based code, but runs it as real stack-based code.